# grunt build giving different output

Tags: html, css, angularjs, gruntjs

I have empty cells in the table (`<td></td>`). The CSS property of empty cells is

```
table tr td:empty {
    width: 25px;
}
```

For the table --

```
<table style="empty-cells:show;"><!-- rows and columns --></table>
```

This code is working fine but after I do a grunt build, the property for empty cells is not getting loaded although it is in the minified CSS.
Any possible reason for this or any solution to it?

Comment: what's the final output of html and css after the build task?

Comment: The css and html files haven't changed at all, they are the same. The quick fix that worked was using inline css but I still don't get why the same html and css files are giving different outputs.

Comment: A **JSFiddle** would really help to debug this.